# GRUB screen missing

Tags: 11.04

Hi I downloaded the updates required for ubuntu and then restarted the PC instead of the Pink grub screen . I got a black screen saying press TAB key for command lists. The command line had grub>.
I am not able to see the ubuntu loading too . Can anyone help on this one ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your grub file is corrupt.  With boot-repair you will be able to resolve this problem.  Look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair