# Why GRUB is missing after update?

Tags: updates, boot-failure

I am running an alternate install of Ubuntu 11.10.  I just ran the latest update which required a re-boot.  When I rebooted, my desktop stops at the POST (Power on self test).  My computer is set up with Logical volumes (which is why I used the alternated install).

I cannot get to the boot (grub) prompt.  I can load the Ubuntu Live CD and see my first drive (40 GB) but cannot access my logical volumes.

I am still somewhat new to linuc and need help.  How can I get this desktop to working again without losing my very valuable (and not backed up) information?

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/97346/47206